# How to obtain the absolute path of apache userdir

Tags: apache2, mod-userdir

Is there any way to obtain the absolute path of the apache userdir (the path that `http://localhost/~username/` maps to, given that it is enabled in the apache configurations). A table, which UserDir directives correspond to which paths can be found at https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_userdir.html. For example,

```
UserDir directive used  Translated path
UserDir public_html     ~bob/public_html/one/two.html
UserDir /usr/web        /usr/web/bob/one/two.html
UserDir /home/*/www     /home/bob/www/one/two.html
```

I want to get the "Translated path" (preferably as absolute path) for the user currently logged in, given that it is enabled in the apache configurations. Of course I can find out manually but my question is how to determine it automatically. My hope was that there is a functionality like `apache2 --show-current-userdir` that just prints it.

Comment: `cd ~/` takes you to the user dir of the authorized user. But i dont think apache has its own userdir so im confused to what exactly you are asking.

Comment: @JasonJoslin Yes, my question was not clear, I updated it. Thank you.